# GRU layer works fine but LSTM layer gives value error : too many values to unpack expected 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am using the tensorflow image captioning tutorial to train a model. They have used GRU in decoder but i want to use LSTM based decoder or infact bidirectional LSTM if possible.. GRU works fine but if i replace it with LSTM or bidirectional LSTM it gives the error said in title

The decoder logic that works with GRU is ggiven below, i want to use LSTM or bidirectional LSTM in the place of GRU

````
  def __init__(self, embedding_dim, units, vocab_size):
    super(RNN_Decoder, self).__init__()
    self.units = units

    self.embedding = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_dim)
    self.gru = tf.keras.layers.GRU(self.units,
                                   return_sequences=True,
                                   return_state=True,
                                   recurrent_initializer='glorot_uniform')
    self.fc1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.units)
    self.fc2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(vocab_size)

    self.attention = BahdanauAttention(self.units)

  def call(self, x, features, hidden):
    # defining attention as a separate model
    context_vector, attention_weights = self.attention(features, hidden)

    # x shape after passing through embedding == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim)
    x = self.embedding(x)

    # x shape after concatenation == (batch_size, 1, embedding_dim + hidden_size)
    x = tf.concat([tf.expand_dims(context_vector, 1), x], axis=-1)

    # passing the concatenated vector to the GRU
    output, state = self.gru(x)

    # shape == (batch_size, max_length, hidden_size)
    x = self.fc1(output)

    # x shape == (batch_size * max_length, hidden_size)
    x = tf.reshape(x, (-1, x.shape[2]))

    # output shape == (batch_size * max_length, vocab)
    x = self.fc2(x)

    return x, state, attention_weights

  def reset_state(self, batch_size):
    return tf.zeros((batch_size, self.units))```
````

Comment: This probably related to the number of internal gates, the states of which tend to get passed along outputs.  LSTM has three gates (input, output and forget gate), whereas GRU has two gates (reset and update gate).